# Sending variables between Fragments and using it in the ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I’m sending a variable and receiving it in a fragment, but it is necessary for the user interface in the ViewModel. What is the best way to access the variable in the ViewModel?

Sending Fragment

```
val gameMode = 1
val action = PlayFragmentDirections.actionPlayFragmentToGameFragment(gameMode)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Receiving Fragment

```
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.game_fragment,
        container,false)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)

    val gameFragmentArgs by navArgs<GameFragmentArgs>()
    var x = gameFragmentArgs.gamemode

    binding.gameViewModel = ViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewModelFactory

GameFragment:

```
    val gameFragmentArgs by navArgs<GameFragmentArgs>()
    val x = gameFragmentArgs.gamemode

    viewModelFactory = GameViewModelFactory(x)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
```

GameViewModelFactory:

```
class GameViewModelFactory(private val gameMode: Int) : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(GameViewModel::class.java)){
        return GameViewModel(gameMode) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
}
```

}